# Determining whether or not a set $S$ is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $S=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]:x-y\in\mathbb Q\}$. Is $S$ Lebesgue measurable? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{q_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be any enumeration of $[-1,1]\cap\Bbb Q$. Note that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ the line $$L_n:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y=x+q_n\}$$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. Since Lebesgue measure is countably additive, then $$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}L_n$$ has measure $0$. Now show that $$S\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}L_n,$$ so that $S$ is Lebesgue measurable, and has measure $0$.

Comment: $ (x,y) \in [0,1] × [0,1] $ not in $ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @nim: I'm not claiming that $$S=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}L_n,$$ only that $$S\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}L_n.$$

Comment: @nim: Do you know the result that any subset of a measure $0$ set is again measure $0$? That's the fundamental result that I'm using here.

Comment: yes, I know the result. but vitali example $ E \subseteq \bigcup E_n$ such that $ \lambda ( \bigcup E_n)=0$ and $E $ is not Lebesgue measurable. The example above question, what is the difference? thanks

Comment: The essential difference is that a Vitali set is a subset of $\Bbb R$, constructed by choosing one element from each equivalence class of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$. Each of these equivalence classes is of Lebesgue measure $0$, but there are **uncountably many** such equivalence classes, so we can't draw the conclusion that their union is of Lebesgue measure $0$ (indeed, their union is all of $\Bbb R$, so that is certainly not the case).

Answer (score 2):

The set $S$ is Borel, being the inverse image of the Borel set $\mathbb{Q}$ under the continuous map $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$.  Every Borel set is Lebesgue measurable, hence so is $S$.